# How to find a specific hidden HTML tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to **find** and **override** a specific **hidden** HTML tag (this will appear with mouseover) as `<a>` tag with both `title="Add"` and `evtid="new_item"` and replace (not using setAttribute) the `href` element to `href="something goes here"` with Javascript and jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView">
<div class="ms-acal-header">
    <div>
        <table class="ms-acal-month">
        </table>
        <div class="ms-acal-vlink">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Add" evtid="new_item">
                            <img border="0" src="/_layouts/images/caladd.gif">Add</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My code goes here:**

```
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("OpenDialog1");
 $(document).ready(function OpenDialog1() {
    var nnnn = $("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView");
        var element = nnnn.querySelector('[title="Add"]');
        element.replace("javascript:void(0)", "http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1");

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView")
    .find('a[title="Add"][evtid="new_item"]')
      .attr('href',"http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/kAu5k/)

Comment: Thank you very much. However, it still runs with `javascript:void(0)`. How can I override that function?

Comment: @PMay1903 i just provided a demo.. please inspect that anchor, you will come to know what is going.. :)

Comment: That works quite well as your demo, yet it doesn't affect to the `javascript:void(0)` in SharePoint...

Comment: @PMay1903 i am not expertise with sharepoint.. you can ask another one question regarding this by tagging sharepoint.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("a[href='javascript:void(0)']").attr('href', 'http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. However, it still runs with `javascript:void(0)`. I would like to override that function...

Comment: @PMay1903 pls check now.

Comment: Thank you for your change but how can I to use push() function with jQuery? `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("OpenDialog1");`. I have modified my thread, please take a look on it.